# How to create a new row on the fly by copying previous row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as given below

**edited dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
'time_1' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 12:50:00','2173-04-05 12:59:00','2173-05-04 13:14:00','2173-05-05 13:37:00','2173-07-06 13:39:00','2173-07-08 11:30:00','2173-04-08 16:00:00','2173-04-09 22:00:00','2173-04-11 04:00:00','2173- 04-13 04:30:00','2173-04-14 08:00:00'],
 'val' :[5,5,5,5,1,6,5,5,8,3,4,6]})
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_yes['time_1'])
df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day
```

What I would like to do is **create a new record**

As shown in the below screenshot, you can see that for `subject_id = 1`, his record for `4th` day is missing. So what I am trying to do is `copy the immediate preceding row

[image]

I tried below but didn't help

```
df.groupby('subject_id)['day'].eq(df['day'].shift(-1)).add(1)
```

The new record should have the same content as the previous row but just the date value should be modified (`d+1`) like as shown below

I expect my output to be like as shown below for each `subject_id`. You can see how `new record for day 4 is added`. please note that time component of a new row doesn't really matter. it can be anything (`00:00:00`).

**I only wish to add missing dates between a range in a month. For example subject = 1, in the 4th month has records from 3rd to 5th. but 4th is missing. So we add record for 4th day alone. We don't need 6th,7th etc**

**edited output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are duplicated `date`s after remove times, so you can create helper DataFrame with all dates per `subject_id`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('date')
         .groupby('subject_id')
         .resample('d')
         .last()
         .index
         .to_frame(index=False))
print (df1)
    subject_id       date
0            1 2173-04-03
1            1 2173-04-04
2            1 2173-04-05
3            1 2173-04-06
4            2 2173-04-08
5            2 2173-04-09
6            2 2173-04-10
7            2 2173-04-11
8            2 2173-04-12
9            2 2173-04-13
10           2 2173-04-14
```

Then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and forward filling missing values:

```
df2 = df1.merge(df, how='left').groupby('subject_id', as_index=False).ffill()
```

Last is necessary add days to new added datetimes, one possible solution is add timedeltas created by difference between new `time_1` values with `date`s:

```
dates = df2['time_1'].dt.normalize() 
df2['time_1'] += np.where(dates == df2['date'], 0, df2['date'] - dates)
df2['day'] = df2['time_1'].dt.day
df2['val'] = df2['val'].astype(int)
print (df2)

         date              time_1  val  day
0  2173-04-03 2173-04-03 12:35:00    5    3
1  2173-04-03 2173-04-03 12:50:00    5    3
2  2173-04-03 2173-04-03 12:59:00    5    3
3  2173-04-04 2173-04-04 13:14:00    5    4
4  2173-04-04 2173-04-04 13:37:00    1    4
5  2173-04-05 2173-04-05 13:37:00    1    5
6  2173-04-06 2173-04-06 13:39:00    6    6
7  2173-04-06 2173-04-06 11:30:00    5    6
8  2173-04-08 2173-04-08 16:00:00    5    8
9  2173-04-09 2173-04-09 22:00:00    8    9
10 2173-04-10 2173-04-10 22:00:00    8   10
11 2173-04-11 2173-04-11 04:00:00    3   11
12 2173-04-12 2173-04-12 04:00:00    3   12
13 2173-04-13 2173-04-13 04:30:00    4   13
14 2173-04-14 2173-04-14 08:00:00    6   14
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Hi, Any idea on how can I resolve the `memory error` that I encounter when I execute the above code for my real data?

Comment: It's throwing error in this line `df2['time_1'] += np.where(dates == df2['date'], 0, df2['date'] - dates)`. I mean memory error.

Comment: Dataset size is also small. `139663` records

Comment: @SSMK - only idea `df2['time_1'] += np.where(dates == df2['date'], pd.Timedelta(0), df2['date'] - dates)` or `df2['time_1'] += np.where(dates == df2['date'], np.timedelta64(0), df2['date'] - dates)` ?

Comment: Hi, One question with this. When we do groupby using `subject_id`, we don't see that column in output. How do I see them in output columns?

Comment: I tried using the `reset_index` method but it doesn't work. `df1.merge(df, how='left').groupby('subject_id', as_index=False).ffill().reset_index()`

Comment: @SSMK - You can use `df2 = df1.merge(df, how='left').groupby(df['subject_id']).ffill()`

Comment: And May I also know what does `+=` in `df2['time_1'] += ` indicate. Usually it looks like increment operator for me. But can you please help me understand?

Comment: It is like `'a' + 'b'` is in pandas/python  `ab`

Comment: So you are adding the dates? I mean from previous value to current value

Comment: But unfortunately groupby on multiple columns doesn't work as you suggested? `dates.merge(df, how='left').groupby(df['subject_id'],df['item_name'], as_index=False).ffill()`

Comment: Need `[]` like `dates.merge(df, how='left').groupby([df['subject_id'],df['item_name']], as_index=False).ffill()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199879/discussion-between-ssmk-and-jezrael).