# How to add missing dates within date interval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
'time_1' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 12:50:00','2173-04-05 
          12:59:00','2173-05-04 13:14:00','2173-05-05 13:37:00','2173-07-06 
          13:39:00','2173-07-08 11:30:00','2173-04-08 16:00:00','2173-04-09 
          22:00:00','2173-04-11 04:00:00','2173- 04-13 04:30:00','2173-04-14 08:00:00'],
 'val' :[5,5,5,5,1,6,5,5,8,3,4,6]})
 df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
 df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day
 df['month'] = df['time_1'].dt.month
```

As you can see from the dataframe above that there are few missing dates in between. **I would like to create new records for those dates and fill in values from the immediate previous row**

```
def dt(df):
   r = pd.date_range(start=df.date.min(), end=df.date.max())
   df.set_index('date').reindex(r)

new_df = df.groupby(['subject_id','month']).apply(dt)
```

This generates all the dates. I only want to find the missing date within the input date interval for each subject for each month

I did try the code from this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57784410/how-to-create-a-new-row-on-the-fly-by-copying-previous-row). Though it helped me but doesn't get me the expected output for this updated/new requirement. As we do left join, it copies all records. I can't do inner join either because it will drop non-match column. I want a mix of left join and inner join

Currently it creates new records for all 365 days in a year which I don't want. something like below. This is not expected

[image]

**I only wish to add missing dates between input date interval as shown below. For example subject = 1, in the 4th month has records from 3rd and 5th. but 4th is missing. So we add record for 4th day alone. We don't need 6th,7th etc unlike current output. Similarly in 7th month, record for 7th day missing. so we just add a new record for that**

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Add what your current solution in the post so it helps us to understand the problem better

Comment: Would be helpful if people who downvote provide some comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is problem you need `resample` for append new days, so it is necessary.

```
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day
df['date'] = df['time_1'].dt.floor('d')

df1 = (df.set_index('date')
         .groupby('subject_id')
         .resample('d')
         .last()
         .index
         .to_frame(index=False))
print (df1)
     subject_id       date
0             1 2173-04-03
1             1 2173-04-04
2             1 2173-04-05
3             1 2173-04-06
4             1 2173-04-07
..          ...        ...
99            2 2173-04-10
100           2 2173-04-11
101           2 2173-04-12
102           2 2173-04-13
103           2 2173-04-14

[104 rows x 2 columns]
```

Idea is remove unnecessary missing rows - you can create threshold for minimum consecutive mising values (here 5) and remove rows (created new column fro easy test):

```
df2 = df1.merge(df, how='left') 

thresh = 5
mask = df2['day'].notna()
s = mask.cumsum().mask(mask)
df2['count'] = s.map(s.value_counts())

df2 = df2[(df2['count'] < thresh) | (df2['count'].isna())]
print (df2)
     subject_id       date              time_1  val   day  count
0             1 2173-04-03 2173-04-03 12:35:00  5.0   3.0    NaN
1             1 2173-04-03 2173-04-03 12:50:00  5.0   3.0    NaN
2             1 2173-04-04                 NaT  NaN   NaN    1.0
3             1 2173-04-05 2173-04-05 12:59:00  5.0   5.0    NaN
32            1 2173-05-04 2173-05-04 13:14:00  5.0   4.0    NaN
33            1 2173-05-05 2173-05-05 13:37:00  1.0   5.0    NaN
95            1 2173-07-06 2173-07-06 13:39:00  6.0   6.0    NaN
96            1 2173-07-07                 NaT  NaN   NaN    1.0
97            1 2173-07-08 2173-07-08 11:30:00  5.0   8.0    NaN
98            2 2173-04-08 2173-04-08 16:00:00  5.0   8.0    NaN
99            2 2173-04-09 2173-04-09 22:00:00  8.0   9.0    NaN
100           2 2173-04-10                 NaT  NaN   NaN    1.0
101           2 2173-04-11 2173-04-11 04:00:00  3.0  11.0    NaN
102           2 2173-04-12                 NaT  NaN   NaN    1.0
103           2 2173-04-13 2173-04-13 04:30:00  4.0  13.0    NaN
104           2 2173-04-14 2173-04-14 08:00:00  6.0  14.0    NaN
```

Last use previous solution:

```
df2 = df2.groupby(df['subject_id']).ffill()
dates = df2['time_1'].dt.normalize() 
df2['time_1'] += np.where(dates == df2['date'], 0, df2['date'] - dates)
df2['day'] = df2['time_1'].dt.day
df2['val'] = df2['val'].astype(int)
print (df2)
     subject_id       date              time_1  val  day  count
0             1 2173-04-03 2173-04-03 12:35:00    5    3    NaN
1             1 2173-04-03 2173-04-03 12:50:00    5    3    NaN
2             1 2173-04-04 2173-04-04 12:50:00    5    4    1.0
3             1 2173-04-05 2173-04-05 12:59:00    5    5    1.0
32            1 2173-05-04 2173-05-04 13:14:00    5    4    NaN
33            1 2173-05-05 2173-05-05 13:37:00    1    5    NaN
95            1 2173-07-06 2173-07-06 13:39:00    6    6    NaN
96            1 2173-07-07 2173-07-07 13:39:00    6    7    1.0
97            1 2173-07-08 2173-07-08 11:30:00    5    8    1.0
98            2 2173-04-08 2173-04-08 16:00:00    5    8    1.0
99            2 2173-04-09 2173-04-09 22:00:00    8    9    1.0
100           2 2173-04-10 2173-04-10 22:00:00    8   10    1.0
101           2 2173-04-11 2173-04-11 04:00:00    3   11    1.0
102           2 2173-04-12 2173-04-12 04:00:00    3   12    1.0
103           2 2173-04-13 2173-04-13 04:30:00    4   13    1.0
104           2 2173-04-14 2173-04-14 08:00:00    6   14    1.0
```

EDIT: Solution with `reindex` for each month:

```
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day
df['date'] = df['time_1'].dt.floor('d')
df['month'] = df['time_1'].dt.month
```

---

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['date','subject_id'])
          .set_index('date')
         .groupby(['subject_id', 'month'])
         .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(), x.index.max())))
         .rename_axis(('subject_id','month','date'))
         .index
         .to_frame(index=False)
         )
print (df1)
    subject_id  month       date
0            1      4 2173-04-03
1            1      4 2173-04-04
2            1      4 2173-04-05
3            1      5 2173-05-04
4            1      5 2173-05-05
5            1      7 2173-07-06
6            1      7 2173-07-07
7            1      7 2173-07-08
8            2      4 2173-04-08
9            2      4 2173-04-09
10           2      4 2173-04-10
11           2      4 2173-04-11
12           2      4 2173-04-12
13           2      4 2173-04-13
14           2      4 2173-04-14
```

---

```
df2 = df1.merge(df, how='left') 
df2 = df2.groupby(df2['subject_id']).ffill()
dates = df2['time_1'].dt.normalize() 
df2['time_1'] += np.where(dates == df2['date'], 0, df2['date'] - dates)
df2['day'] = df2['time_1'].dt.day
df2['val'] = df2['val'].astype(int)
print (df2)
    subject_id  month       date              time_1  val  day
0            1      4 2173-04-03 2173-04-03 12:35:00    5    3
1            1      4 2173-04-03 2173-04-03 12:50:00    5    3
2            1      4 2173-04-04 2173-04-04 12:50:00    5    4
3            1      4 2173-04-05 2173-04-05 12:59:00    5    5
4            1      5 2173-05-04 2173-05-04 13:14:00    5    4
5            1      5 2173-05-05 2173-05-05 13:37:00    1    5
6            1      7 2173-07-06 2173-07-06 13:39:00    6    6
7            1      7 2173-07-07 2173-07-07 13:39:00    6    7
8            1      7 2173-07-08 2173-07-08 11:30:00    5    8
9            2      4 2173-04-08 2173-04-08 16:00:00    5    8
10           2      4 2173-04-09 2173-04-09 22:00:00    8    9
11           2      4 2173-04-10 2173-04-10 22:00:00    8   10
12           2      4 2173-04-11 2173-04-11 04:00:00    3   11
13           2      4 2173-04-12 2173-04-12 04:00:00    3   12
14           2      4 2173-04-13 2173-04-13 04:30:00    4   13
15           2      4 2173-04-14 2173-04-14 08:00:00    6   14
```

Comment: Will try now. upvoted. Isn't it possible to find `min` and `max' for each subject for each month?, so we can just use `difference` method to add missing dates. something like this `idx = pd.period_range(min(df.date), max(df.date))`

Comment: So we will get for subject = 1 and for 4th month, we will have `min` date as `2173-04-03` and max date as `2173-04-05`. Now we just need to add missing `2173-04-04` in between. Just asking.

Comment: Anyway I am marking this as a solution as it works. However I think there should be a way to do this with `min` and `max` approach for each subject in each month. Thanks for your help. I also updated the post with I am actually trying to do. Can you help with that?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, another quick question. I see for few records the dates aren't added. Instead it remains as `NA`

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
def fill_dates(df):
    result = pd.DataFrame()
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        if i == 0:
            result = result.append(row)
        else:
            start_date = result.iloc[-1]['time_1']
            end_date = row['time_1']
#            print(start_date, end_date)
            delta = (end_date - start_date).days
#            print(delta)
            if delta > 0 and start_date.month == end_date.month:
                for j in range(delta):
                    day = start_date + timedelta(days=j+1)
                    new_row = result.iloc[-1].copy()
                    new_row['time_1'] = day
                    new_row['remarks'] = 'added'
                    if new_row['time_1'].date() != row['time_1'].date():
                        result = result.append(new_row)
                result = result.append(row)
            else:
                result = result.append(row)
    result.reset_index(inplace = True)
    return result
```

Comment: I can't use for loop over my dataset. Nonetheless,Upvoted for your effort and time.